# What ROS packages shall I install

Tags: ros, raspberrypi, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there, I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Raspberry Pi 2 and have also installed the ROS base (bare bones). So my question is that what packages do I need to make a bot that could make a map of the surrounding a and then autonomously navigate? For ex- SLAM, gazebo, etc

Thanks & Regards
Mukut

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230068/what-ros-packages-shall-i-install/) by [mukut_noob](https://answers.ros.org/users/26182/mukut_noob/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2016-03-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Definitely not Gazebo if you're putting together a real robot :P

I'm guessing you're planning on placing the RPi on a chassis and hooking it up to motors/wheels and a LiDAR, right? Once that's done, I would download `gmapping` for SLAM and `navigation` for localization and moving around in the map created by SLAM.

You'd also need to find or write drivers and ROS bindings for the motors and LiDAR of course.

---

Originally posted by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) with karma: 1788 on 2016-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mukut_noob](https://answers.ros.org/users/26182/mukut_noob/) on 2016-03-24**:
Okk...but I am thinking of using an Ultrasonic Sensor or an IR Range finder, because LIDAR is just too expensive. And  what bindings and drivers do I have to write? Do u mean the program to run the motors and get data from the sensor?

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-03-25**:
OK. Loosely speaking: Drivers = ROS-independent code that interfaces with the sensors/actuators and ROS bindings = ROS code (node) that uses ("wraps") the drivers in order to, among other things, publish the streams of sensor data. Here's a good example: https://github.com/mikeferguson/neato_robot

**Comment by [mukut_noob](https://answers.ros.org/users/26182/mukut_noob/) on 2016-03-25**:
Okk thanks spmaniato, I am facing some problems installing the navigation package, I found some similar posts but found no suck answer to it. Here's the link : http://answers.ros.org/question/230117/ros-navigation-package-error/

**Comment by [mukut_noob](https://answers.ros.org/users/26182/mukut_noob/) on 2016-03-30**:
What do you mean by " **navigation** for localization and moving around the in the map created by SLAM "? Do you mean the navigation stack?

**Comment by [mukut_noob](https://answers.ros.org/users/26182/mukut_noob/) on 2016-03-30**:
Can I use the nav2d instead of navigation? Because I am facing some problems installing it as told in my earlier post.

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-03-31**:
Yeah, I meant the navigation stack (`ros-indigo-navigation`). I don't know much about `nav2d`, sorry.